# Error loading the page in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Previous page:

```
MainController *bookview=[[MainController alloc]init];
    bookview.bookString=booksStr;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookview animated:YES];
```

-transform to next view page:-

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfPagesForPageFlipper:(AFKPageFlipper *)pageFlipper {
    return self.view.bounds.size.width > self.view.bounds.size.height ? ceil((float) CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDocument) / 2) : CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDocument);
}


- (UIView *) viewForPage:(NSInteger) page inFlipper:(AFKPageFlipper *) pageFlipper {
    PDFRendererView *result = [[[PDFRendererView alloc] initWithFrame:pageFlipper.bounds] autorelease];
    result.pdfDocument = pdfDocument;
    result.pageNumber = page;

    return result;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title=bookString;
    NSLog(@"the bookstring value is %@",bookString);

}
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View management


- (void) loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    flipper = [[[AFKPageFlipper alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    flipper.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    flipper.dataSource = self;
    NSLog(@"loadview loaded successfully %@",bookString);
    [self.view addSubview:flipper];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization and memory management


- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}


- (id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        pdfDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AppleScript Language Guide" ofType:@"pdf"]]);
        NSLog(@"this is maincontroller");
        [self loadView];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDocument);
    [super dealloc];
}
```

and I'm not able to transfer the string value and

- changing property opaque in transform-only layer, will have no effect

page not transfer to the nextview

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
MainController *bookview=[[MainController alloc]init];
bookview.bookString=booksStr;
[self presentViewcontroller:bookview animated:YES];
```

MainController.h

```
NSString *bookview;
```

set property;

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bookview;
```

MainController.m

```
@synthesize bookview;
-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
      NSLog(@"%@",bookview);
 }
```

Comment: presentviewcontroller works fine but value not at all parsing from oneview to another

Comment: <CATransformLayer: 0x4b5eaf0> - changing property opaque in transform-only layer, will have no effect i;m getting warning like this and string value didn't parse at all

Comment: or u wil use appdelegate method

Comment: no not using appdelegates i need the answer y it occurs a warning like that

Comment: @Unknown The `NSLog(@"%@", bookview);` line is using the member variable, _not_ the property. A common paradigm is to synthesize via something like `@synthesize bookview = _bookview;` so that you get an error when accessing the member variable instead of going through the property. The correct line would be `NSLog(@"%@", self.bookview);`.